# Can't request uber rides (or other class methods) with OAUTH 2.0 client using Uber API

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I successfully got the access token but ran into problems after making a client using OAUTH 2.0 credentials. I pretty much followed the example on the python SDK example on github.

Here is my code:

```
from utils import import_oauth2_credentials
from uber_rides.client import UberRidesClient
from uber_rides.session import OAuth2Credential
from uber_rides.session import Session

credentials2 = import_oauth2_credentials()
oauth2credential = OAuth2Credential(
            client_id=credentials2.get('client_id'),
            access_token=credentials2.get('access_token'),
            expires_in_seconds=credentials2.get('expires_in_seconds'),
            scopes=credentials2.get('scopes'),
            grant_type=credentials2.get('grant_type'),
            redirect_url=credentials2.get('redirect_url'),
            client_secret=credentials2.get('client_secret'),
            refresh_token=credentials2.get('refresh_token'),
        )

session = Session(oauth2credential=oauth2credential)

uber_client = UberRidesClient(session, sandbox_mode=True)

print uber_client

response = uber_client.get_products(37.77, -122.41)

print response
```

I can print out the uber_client object:

```
<uber_rides.client.UberRidesClient object at 0x10deeae50>
```

The error message I got is:

```
raise ClientError(response)
ClientError: The request contains bad syntax or cannot be filled due to a fault from the client sending the request."
```

I'm wondering what is the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issues. The problem is that I imported the oauth credentials from a oauth2_session_store.yaml file that was not updated properly to reflect my current access_token.

The root problem:

```
credentials2 = import_oauth2_credentials()
```

So lesson learned: check the access token to see if it's current.